# How to splice an object up and down with the up and down keyboard key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, array-splice

I'm having trouble using splice to move individual objects from an array up and down the sequence by pressing the up and down arrow keys.

i have an array of objects that look like this:

```
$scope.peoples = [  
   {  
      "seqNo":0,
      "address":{  
        "street": "123 abc"
      },
      "id":11,
      "name":{  
         "first":"adf"
      }
   },
   {  
      "seqNo":1,
      "address":{  
        "street": "123 bbc"
      },
      "id":24,
      "name":{  
         "first":"adf"
      }
   },
   {  
      "seqNo":2,
      "address":{  
        "street": "123 cbs"
      },
      "id":14,
      "name":{  
         "first":"adf"
      }
   },
]
```

my js:

```
      var moveUp = function(from, to) {
        $scope.peoples.splice(to, 0, $scope.peoples.splice(from, 1)[0]);
      };

      var moveDown = function(from, to) {
        $scope.peoples.splice(from, 0, $scope.peoples.splice(to, 1)[0]);
      };

      $scope.keyEvent = function (people) {
          $scope.keydownkeycode = event.keyCode;
          if (event.keyCode === 38) {
            moveUp(0, 1);
          } else if (event.keyCode === 40) {
            moveDown(0, 1);
          }
      };
```

currently it only moves the first object and the second object from the array up and down...not exactly sure how to go about solving this issue. anyone else have done anything like this before?

EDIT:

my html:

```
<tr ng-keydown="keydownevt(people)" tabindex="0" ng-repeat="people in peoples">
        <td class="people-col">
          <div>{{people.name.first}}</div>
          <div>{{people.address.street}}</div>
          <div>{{people.id}}</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: How do you know which object to move? Is there some click event to select the object? ... Just curious, are you using some framework like angular to reflect the people-array changes in the HTML?

Comment: i'm using angular i can post my html as well if that helps

Comment: Try using `ng-repeat="(key, value) in people"`, and for each person template add `ng-click=setPerson(key)`... Create `setPerson` function in your scope and store that key... then, use this key in your `keyEvent` function.

Comment: well i want to use the splice methods when i press the up and down key so ng-click prob wont work?

Comment: The `ng-click` event was just an idea to know which object to move.

Comment: Your logic is flawed. Adding a listener to each `person` in `peoples` means that all of your `person`s are trying to change their position at the same time. This makes no sense. This is why `ngKeydown` was written with `input` elements in mind, not just random HTML elements.